# Enabling hermes in android app crashing app in react native version 0.68

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Enabling Hermes in react native giving below error without hermes working fine in android :
I have used react native code in existing native android app. When we try to build below code its crashing
RN - 0.68.3
gradle plugin - 3.6.0
gradle version -6.8

```
 mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
                .setApplication(getApplication())
                .setCurrentActivity(this)
                .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
                .setJSMainModulePath("index")
                .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
               .addPackage(new RNGestureHandlerPackage())
                .addPackage(new ReanimatedPackage())
                .addPackage(new SafeAreaContextPackage())
                .addPackage(new RNScreensPackage())
                .addPackage(new RNCMaskedViewPackage())
                .addPackage(new SvgPackage())
                .addPackage(new ReactCheckBoxPackage())
                .addPackage(new VectorIconsPackage())
                .addPackage(new AsyncStoragePackage())
                .addPackage((new LottiePackage()))
                .addPackage(new RNPackages())
                .setUseDeveloperSupport(true)
                .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
                .build();  // ==> crashes here with below error
```

Error Logs:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.react.jscexecutor.JSCExecutor
        at com.facebook.react.jscexecutor.JSCExecutor.loadLibrary(JSCExecutor.java:24)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.getDefaultJSExecutorFactory(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:351)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.build(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:318)
        at com.onebank.RNActivityOneBank.onCreate(RNActivityTest.java:83)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1312)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3423)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3602)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2067)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7660)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so
        SoSource 0: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.test.debug/lib-main flags = 1]
        SoSource 1: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/~~FPj1_T2lPllKbeMplU88ng==/com.test.debug-6k3XZjaBJ5_hN_CFOFMwNQ==/lib/arm64 flags = 0]
        SoSource 2: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /vendor/lib64 flags = 2]
        SoSource 3: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /system/lib64 flags = 2]
        Native lib dir: /data/app/~~FPj1_T2lPllKbeMplU88ng==/com.test.debug-6k3XZjaBJ5_hN_CFOFMwNQ==/lib/arm64
     result: 0
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:896)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoNameImpl(SoLoader.java:725)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:649)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:629)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:577)
        at com.facebook.react.jscexecutor.JSCExecutor.loadLibrary(JSCExecutor.java:24)
        at com.facebook.react.jscexecutor.JSCExecutor.<clinit>(JSCExecutor.java:20)
```

Comment: facing the same error, was the issue resolved for you?

Comment: @AayushAnand Please use this   .setJavaScriptExecutorFactory(new HermesExecutorFactory()) in your ReactInstanceManager.builder()